# how to remove the line between they rotateX

Tags: css, transform

like this demo:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sorAB

How can i remove the white line between the block when they are rotateX.

Maybe it can without the translate/margin/top property.

Bad english. XD

Answer (score 0):

You can add a border around your blocks : 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vndfc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is difficult to make the div match exactly.

Your layout is exact. However, slight round-outs in dimensions produce that gap between divs.

But, if you increase the sizes, then the corners don't match anymore.

One posible solution is to set a shadow between divs. And make this shadow slightly smaller than the div, so that it won't be visible in the angles:

```
#girl{
    width:300px;height:400px;margin:100px auto 0;
  -webkit-perspective:1000;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: center center;
}
#girl .item{
  height: 100px;width:100%;background-color:#333;
  -webkit-transform-origin:top;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px -1px #333;
}
#girl .item.i1{-webkit-transform:rotateX(45deg);}
#girl .item.i2{-webkit-transform:translateY(100px) rotateX(-90deg);}
#girl .item.i3{-webkit-transform:translateY(100px) rotateX(90deg);}
#girl .item.i4{-webkit-transform:translateY(100px) rotateX(-90deg);}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jviwz)